# PHP XML element with HTML formatting returning empty results

Tags: php, xml, parsing, html-entities

Sadly I have no control of the XML data that I receive. It's an export from a system I have no access to. However I can edit the file as needed after I have received it.

The XML file has about 90.000 lines and contains about 900 items I need to parse and then import into another system.

My issue is that the XML contains (sometimes) HTML data within the elements I'm parsing. When there is HTML data, the parsing return empty.

Example XML data:

```
<item>
     <title>This is the tile</title>
     <description><p>This is a description</p></description>
     <comment>&lt;p&gt;This is an example&lt;/p&gt;</comment>
</item>
```

When parsing, I'm able to get the "Title" content. However the "Description" content returns empty results due to the

tags.

If I remove the

tags OR change them to `&lt;p&gt;` formatting, then I'm able to get the results I need.

**My issue** is, that the XML data sometimes has HTML tags (p, a, img, h2 and so on) and also sometimes multiple HTML tags and/or Child tags. I would like to gat all content into one string.

Compared to the XML example above, I've tried the following but with no results:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("uploaded_file.xml");

$item = $xml->xpath("/rss/channel/item");

foreach($item as $task) 
{

  $title    = $task->title;                             // Works
  $description = $task->description;                   // Empty
  $description = strip_tags($task->description);       // Empty
  $description = htmlentities($task->description);     // Empty
  $comment= strip_tags($task->comment);                // Works
...
```

If I manually remove the HTML tags from the "Description" element then I get normal results. However manually doing so is not an option in such a large file and the tags are not always the same. Sometimes b, p, ul, li, a and so on.

I was hoping that htmlentities() would convert the HTML to a XML supported format (ie. `&lt;p&gt;`) but it does not seem to work.

Any assistance would be appricaiated. Can provide more exmaples if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Have finally found a solution that works for me with using **->asXML()**

```
 $description = strip_tags($task->description->asXML());
```